# When I try to login to Django admin via https, python server was closed without any error

Tags: django, https, django-admin, codeanywhere

I follow the Official Django tutorial, but I´m stucked in the point where I should login into Admin page. I can fill name and password, but after hit Log in button, python development server ends. I´m running them using this command `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:3000`

I´m running Linux container on Codeanywhere using Python 3.7 and Django 3.1.
Only output I get is:
        Watching for file changes with StatReloader
        Performing system checks...

```
    System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
    October 04, 2019 - 16:14:47
    Django version 3.1, using settings 'buky.settings'
    Starting development server at http://0.0.0.0:3000/
    Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
    [04/Oct/2019 16:14:48] "GET /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
    [04/Oct/2019 16:14:49] "GET /admin/login/?next=/admin/ HTTP/1.1" 200         1916
    [04/Oct/2019 16:14:49] "GET /static/admin/css/base.css HTTP/1.1" 200 16378
    [04/Oct/2019 16:14:49] "GET /static/admin/css/login.css HTTP/1.1" 200 1233
    [04/Oct/2019 16:14:49] "GET /static/admin/css/responsive.css HTTP/1.1" 200 18052
    [04/Oct/2019 16:14:49] "GET /static/admin/css/fonts.css HTTP/1.1" 200 423
    [04/Oct/2019 16:14:50] "GET /static/admin/fonts/Roboto-Regular-webfont.woff HTTP/1.1" 200 85876
    [04/Oct/2019 16:14:50] "GET /static/admin/fonts/Roboto-Light-webfont.woff HTTP/1.1" 200 85692
    [04/Oct/2019 16:14:57] "POST /admin/login/?next=/admin/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
```

My urls.py is like in tutorial:

```
    urlpatterns = [
         path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
         path('polls/', include('polls.urls')),
       ]
```

What can be wrong?

Thanks Alex

Answer (score 0):

I updated my python version from 3.7.0 to 3.8.1 and the problem was fixed for me.

Hope it helps for you too! Cheers